# Using youtube_it gem in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube-api

I'm working on a simple rails project where I can create a post. My post model has a field for youtube video url so that when I create a post with the youtube video url, in the show page of the post the video would be embedded automatically and the users can watch the video from my web app due to the youtube video url provided.

I am trying to accomplish this with the `youtube_it` gem but I don't know how to go about this. Any brief code sample in making this possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to use the Youtube API?  I would just search the user-supplied url for the ID string that identifies the video, then insert that in to a template for embedding youtube videos on pages.

The HTML embed code for a video looks like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zrVL81FC77w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So just replace the zrVL81FC77w with the ID of the user's video.

If you want to, you can probably check if the video exists by doing an HTTP request to YouTube from your server, but that is not necessary for what you are trying to do.

Comment: very nice so this means i can just save the video id in my database and render it as you explained

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rails app that has example youtube_it code in it.

https://github.com/chebyte/youtube_it_rails_app_example

Comment: pls i wound your app very helpful thank you but i have a little problem using this command `<%= raw yt_client.my_videos %>` it does not give me my list of videos. the videos are not being displayed at all